# How I decide what version of Angular and dependencies I should be using?

Tags: angularjs, bower

How are you supposed to decide on version numbers for the different packages in Angular?

My bower.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "Plan The World",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.7-build.2029+sha.80e7a45",
    "angular-resource": "1.2.7-build.2029+sha.80e7a45",
    "angular-ui-sortable": "angular1.2",
    "angular-route": "1.2.7-build.2029+sha.80e7a45",
    "angular-bootstrap": "master",
    "angular-cookies" : "master",
    "angular-animate": "~1.2.x",
    "jquery-file-upload": "9.5.0",
    "alertify": "0.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.2.7-build.2029+sha.80e7a45"
  }
}
```

and I've currently got a problem which is I believe being caused by the angular-animate package being out of sync with the others. However I don't have a clue how to resolve this or what versions to start changing.

What's the right way to deal with all of these different package versions? In my Rails gemfile I generally don't specify versions unless I have to - is there a similar way to go for Angular and bower?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *always* use the same version of AngularJS packages (`angular-`). Today all those files are published / released from the same source tree and don't have independent life-cycle.

For example you seem to mixing versions of `angular-animate` (~1.2.x) with `angular` (1.2.7-build.2029+sha.80e7a45). You should use the same version for both files (and for all the files from the AngularJS distribution for that matter).

I'm not sure if there is a way of avoiding repetition the version for each file, though.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your answer. What do I do in order to do that? Do you mean that each package should have the same version number as the main one? Can I specify one package that then defines the version for all of the others or do I have to specify them all individually (even though they need to be the same)?

Comment: Updated the answer. I'm not sure if you can define a package that would drive versions of other packages.... You will probably have to specify the same version multiple times...

Comment: @PeterNixey accepting answers is the way of saying 'thank you' on Stack Overflow :-)